# Access directive scope from parent controller

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs ui tour https://github.com/benmarch/angular-ui-tour 
I have successfully installed the directive,
I now want to initialize the directive in my controller when the page is loaded.

On my routes, I have the following code

```
when('/start', {
    templateUrl: 'start.html',
    controller: 'startController'      
})
```

On the template start.html, I have the following code

```
<div ui-tour class="myClass">
```

So I want to access the tour var of ui-tour scope from startController, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how directive is defined. Does it create a new scope or not? Is it's scope proto inherited or isolated one. The simplest solution is to make your directive not create a new scope but use parent's one. If it is the same scope, simply call a function in the directive from parents controller like you would do for a function in that controller.

For more info about why is not a straightforward answer and what are the options when defining directives concerning scope, I find this well explained on the following link:

[directives and scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the documentation, it looks like it's possible. Via the [uiTourService documentation](https://github.com/benmarch/angular-ui-tour#tour-service)

```
yourModule.controller('startController',
['$scope', 'uiTourService', function($scope, uiTourService) {
    var myTour = uiTourService.getTour();
}]);
```